# What is the meaning of "sudo apt-get install \ ca-certificates \ curl \ gnupg \ lsb-release"?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am installing docker in Ubuntu after reading the official documentation and there i saw this command. What does this mean? I am new to Linux and Docker.

Also, what does following command do:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

Comment: The backslashes in the install command just indicate that the command continues on the next line. So an equivalent command on a single line is `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release`. The command installs 4 packages.

Comment: This threw me off as well. Why is it written like that? There is plenty of room to have put it all on one line instead of confusing people with this weirdness; and especially odd when further down [the same page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository) they have an equally long apt-get install command which this time they *do* put on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

The first command `curl` downloads a public key from docker, that is specific to ubuntu and is installed what is called a keyring, which is then used to verify the docker packages

the second command `echo` writes your current OS-version alongside some other configuration text into a file that is used by `apt` when you install anything docker related